# getString(R.string.res_name) giving java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, string, android-activity, android-8.0-oreo

I stuck across unusual issue. When I'm accessing the string resource in my `activity` (LevelTwoActivity) it is giving me below issue.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.package/com.package.LevelTwoActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2906)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1605)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
               Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
                  at android.content.res.StringBlock.nativeGetString(Native Method)
                  at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:82)
                  at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceValue(AssetManager.java:236)
                  at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceText(AssetManager.java:164)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:334)
                  at android.content.Context.getText(Context.java:543)
                  at com.package.LevelTwoActivity.loadArraysFromResources(LevelTwoActivity.java:1586)
                  at com.package.LevelTwoActivity.onCreate(LevelTwoActivity.java:133)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2906) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1605) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
 E/Jellow: exception caught
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dsource.idc.jellowintl/com.package.LevelTwoActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2906)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1605)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
          at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
       Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
          at android.content.res.StringBlock.nativeGetString(Native Method)
          at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:82)
          at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceValue(AssetManager.java:236)
          at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceText(AssetManager.java:164)
          at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:334)
          at android.content.Context.getText(Context.java:543)
          at com.package.LevelTwoActivity.loadArraysFromResources(LevelTwoActivity.java:1586)
          at com.package.LevelTwoActivity.onCreate(LevelTwoActivity.java:133)
          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2906) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1605) 
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
          at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

The line in code is follows

```
    LevelTwoVerbiageModel verbiageModel = new Gson()
            .fromJson(getString(R.string.levelTwoVerbiage), LevelTwoVerbiageModel.class);
```

The string reosurce is follows:

```
<string name="levelTwoVerbiage">
    {\"arrays\":[[[
        \"I like to greet others\",
        \"I really like to greet others\",
        \"I want to greet others\"],[],[],
        ....
        ....
        \"I really don’t want\",
        \"I don’t feel very safe\",
        \"I really don’t feel very safe\"
]]]}
</string>
```

The resource I'm acessing is json string and around 135000 characters in length. It is stored under values folder but in file named arrays-level-two.xml .
In a strange manner, code was working until I've updated my test device. Now, it is not working. The code is works perfectly on other test devices with different api level.

The device details on which it is failing are:

```
Device name: MI A1
Android version: 8.0.0
Android patch level: 1 April 2018
Build number: OPR1.170623.026.V9.5.10.0.DHMIFA
```

I'm not able to identify why accessing string resource giving me : `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException.`

Does anybody have any pointer what went wrong?

Thanks in advance.
-Rahul

Comment: can we see your LevelTwoActivity?

Comment: It looks like you're loading arrays >> loadArraysFromResources, the problem might not be releated to getString

Comment: Post your strings.xml and activity code where you are trying to access it.

Comment: is there a reason for having a string which contains 135000 characters in strings.xml rather than adding a raw resource file?

Comment: @ZUNJAE The file has regional versions. If keep it into values. It will be helpful to get string resource according to region.

Comment: @Mr.Rabbit is added piece of code suffice for your understanding?

Comment: I face the same awful errors in OREO. I have big texts in an app made for readings and now I have to change it somehow

Answer (score 1):

@Rahul - I don't know why Android Oreo is throwing this exception. It may be due to added limitations in the number of characters used in a string resource. Also using a string with around 135000 characters seems a bad practice to me. Instead, I would suggest you use `string-array` and then get it as an array of strings `String[]` in your code and then use it.

That way you don't even need to use Gson for parsing to and from Json.

Example:

> strings.xml

```
<string-array name="my_items">
    <item>Item1</item>
    <item>Item2</item>
    <item>Item3</item>
    ...
</string-array>
```

> MyFile.java

```
String[] myItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_items);
```

Use it as `myItems[index_you_want_to_access]`

Comment: Thank you for this help. I've found they have changed in this security update                                                         https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/2018-04-01

Comment: @RahulJidge Consider accepting or upvoting the answer if it was of any help. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Rabbit: Thanks for the solution. It worked me too. But how you got to know that this is the issue and 135000 is the limit ?

Comment: @akashPatra - I have just provided the better practice to implement such situation, not the solution. Also, the questioner has mentioned about the length of the string he is using(135000), I do not know the exact limit.